# Android: Rect actually represents two rectangles

Tags: android, rect

A Rect has parameters left, top, right and bottom to represent a rectangle, but it actually represents two rectangles. See the diagram below:

[image]

When i rotated the rectangle on the left using:

```
matrix.setRotate(45,myRect.exactCenterX(), myRect.exactCenterY());
matrix.mapRect(myRect);
```

I was expecting the rectangle in Red color, but I got the one in Blue color. Because the same parameters (left, top, right, bottom) represents two rectangles.

Is this a problem with Android's Rect? How can I get the rectangle in the Red color?

Comment: How did you rotate the rectangle?

Comment: Your code would be very usefull.

Comment: using matrix. added to my question.

Comment: what do you mean by "How can I get the rectangle" ?

Comment: @pskink. I am getting the blue rectangle instead of red

Comment: @usman you are getting? how are you gettig that?

Comment: @pskink please read the problem again. i have rotated the rectangle on the left side, which results in the Blue rectangle and not the red rectangle.

Comment: @usman if you want four rotated corners use mapPoints with an array of eight floats l, t, r, t, r, b, l, b

Comment: @pskink yes that would be the alternate method, also mentioned by Ridcully. I wanted to know the problem with it.

Comment: @usmen this is the only method as RectF keeps only 4 foats (2 corners) and not 8 (4 corners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Rect holds four integer coordinates for a rectangle. The rectangle is
>   represented by the coordinates of its 4 edges (left, top, right
>   bottom).

The `Rect` class is basically just a set of the coordinates for left/top and right/bottom corner. It has no concept of rotation whatsoever.

Comment: basically what you do is rotate two points (top-left and bottom-right) around the center of the rectangle. So I guess the simplest solution would be to apply the rotation to all 4 corner-points of the rect.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the rect before you rotate:

Instead of this:

```
matrix.setRotate(45,myRect.exactCenterX(), myRect.exactCenterY());
matrix.mapRect(myRect);
```

Try this:

```
matrix.mapRect(myRect);    
matrix.setRotate(45,myRect.exactCenterX(), myRect.exactCenterY());
```

Comment: the problem is: two points represents two rectangles. The rotation of points is being performed right.